# Set animated (video or gif) background for Lock Screen in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, lock-screen, animations

Is it possible to set animated background for the lock screen of Ubuntu 14.04 (or higher)? Wasn't able to find any significant information about setting of video or gif animation for Lock Screen only. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[image: 1]

Slideshow on your lock-screen can be easily achieved using [MDM](https://github.com/linuxmint/mdm). To install it do (from [noobslab](http://www.noobslab.com/2015/01/mdm-display-manager-and-themes-are-now.html)):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:noobslab/mint
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mdm mdm-themes
```